# Strange way to define an ellipse in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections

I'm asked to prove that

### $|z-i||z+i|=2$

defines an ellipse in the plane.

I have tried replacing $z = x+iy $  in the previous equation and brute forcing the result to no avail. Considering that $ |z-i||z+i| = |z^2+1| $ eases the algebra a bit but didn't help me that much.

Edit: I know it seems like there's a missing plus sign: $|z-i| + |z+i| = 2$ in the question, but that's what the exercise says.

In fact, the next exercise wants us to prove that $ |z-1||z+i| = 2$ defines a line in the complex plane.

Comment: I think there's a mistake. There's supposed to be a plus sign between the two absolute values, not multiplication .

Comment: I agree with you. That's definitely not an ellipse, although it looks really close to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locus of the points $P$ which have the product of their distances from two given points (foci) constant is known as a the [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval). Thus I also think that there should be a + sign rather than multiplication in your expression.

Comment: I completely agree with you . However, I'm surprised by the fact that plotting this equation does in fact show an ellipse. Check it out: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E2%2B2(x%5E2-y%5E2)%3D3

Btw, I'm new to this site, so forgive me if my etiquette is not up to standards.

Comment: @JairoPeña It looks like an ellipse, but it isn't. This is a special case of the Cassini oval in which the parameter $e$ from the Wikipedia page is equal to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I completely understand now. Just out of curiosity, what do you think was the mistake in the second exercise, where I'm asked to find a straight line from the equation. (I plotted that equation and it's definitely not a straight line lol)

Comment: @JairoPeña Not sure about it, but it could be $|z-1| \div |z+i|=1$.

Answer (score 3):

This expression *doesn't* define an ellipse. It's the set of those points of the plane such that the *products* of its distances to $i$ and to $-i$ is equal to $2$. If we were talking about the *sum* of the distances, then, yes, it would be an ellipse.

In order to prove that it is not an ellipse, note that four of the points of this set are $\pm1$ and $\pm\sqrt3\,i$. Furthermore, the set is symmetric with respect to both axis. There is one and only one ellipse fulfilling these conditions:$$\left\{x+yi\in\mathbb{C}\,\middle|\,x^2+\frac{y^2}3=1\right\}.$$One of the points of this ellipse is $z_0=\frac12+\frac{3i}2$. But $|z_0-i|.|z_0+i|=\frac{\sqrt{13}}2$. Therefore, your set is *not* an ellipse.

Comment: @JairoPeña Please read the new paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. It is definitely not an ellipse. 
Just to tickle your brain, what do you think was the mistake in the second exercise, where they want us to find a straight line.

Comment: @JairoPeña I have no idea,

Comment: Considering that this whole question was based on a mistake, I'm going to delete it from the site.

Comment: @JairoPeña No you won't. You can't do that.

Comment: I just noticed I can't. Still, I would like for a moderator to delete it since it's misleading.

Comment: @JairoPeña Don't delete! The problem and solution of noticing it's not an ellipse is instructive. Someone with similar problems might find this question by searching. You might change the title though.